# Алгоритм сортировки работает не правильно

Tags: java

Вот код:

```
package Arrays;


public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int array[]={9,10,4,7,6,1,5,8,2,3};
        int temp;
    
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){ 
              if (array[i] < array[j]){
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
              } 
          }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

И это он выводит:
9
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10

Цифра 9 игнорируется.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: `j = 0` сделайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во внутреннем цикле `for`, нужно изменить в блоке инициализации счётчика значение переменной `int j` на `0`, а у вас стоит `1`.

```
package Arrays;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = {9, 10, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 8, 2, 3};
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Зачем велосипеды делать?

```java
int [] array = new int [] {9,10,4,7,6,1,5,8,2,3};  

Arrays.sort(array);   

System.out.println("Отсортировано: ");  

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)   
{
  System.out.println(array[i]);   
}
```

Comment: В ознакомительных целях! Для саморазвития!

Comment: Я именно из-за подобных велосипедов сейчас пишу часто говно код)

Comment: Разве это не ваша проблема? Просто вы так преподносите, как будто автор в чем то виноват.

Comment: Моей целью не было обвинить автора, я просто спросил у него зачем делать велосипед и показал что уже есть готовые инструменты для этого